# Could abs(random()) % someNumberGreaterThanZero return zero?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT foo FROM bar
WHERE id >= (abs(random()) % (SELECT max(id) FROM bar))
LIMIT 1;
```

I saw this in another answer as an alternative to ORDER BY random(). I need to make sure `id` would always be greater than zero. Do I have to change `>=` to `>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `x % y` returns 0 when `x` is a multiple of `y`, the answer is "Yes, your expression could return 0".

So, if `id` must be greater than 0, you need to use `>` rather than `>=`.  Of course, if the modulo operator didn't return 0, you could still use `>` instead of `>=` and you'd get the same effect.

Comment: It sounds like 1 will likely never get returned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If `abs(random())` returned the value of `max(id)`, then the modulo's result would be zero. Since `abs(random())` can return any value between 0 & 9223372036854775807, this is definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks, for explaining random()'s range.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can return 0 in two ways

Consider that `3 % 3 == 0`, `6 % 3 == 0`, etc. Then you would get 0 if `random()` happens to be `max(id)` or an even divider thereof.

`random()` can also return 0 and `0 % anything == 0`, that is the other possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be > because modulo division can return 0( `a mod a ==0`, `0 mod a == 0`). Also, you might want to check if `(SELECT max(id)` is not null/0 (`a mod 0` is undefined in some systems, or a)